# Solving of the equation $e^{-x\pi}-2e^{-2x\pi}=0$

Tags: exponential-function, substitution, exponential-distribution

If got problems with the answer for $x$ for the equation:

$$e^{-x\pi}-2e^{-2x\pi}=0$$

I don't really know how to start. I tried to substitute $e^x$ but that didn't really work...

I would be happy if someone could provide a little hint for me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: introduce a new variable $y:= e^{-\pi x}$. Also keep in mind that the exponential function is positive everywhere.

Comment: ok lets see:
y-2y^2=0
y(1-2y)=0
y1=0
y2=-0,5

Comment: Ok got it now! thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{ -xπ }-2e^{ -2xπ }=0\\ e^{ -xπ }=2e^{ -2xπ }\\ e^{ xπ }=2\\ x=\frac { \ln { 2 }  }{ \pi  } $$

Answer (score 2):

Come on,

$$e^{-x\pi}=2e^{-2x\pi}\iff -x\pi=\ln2-2x\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=e^{-x\pi}$ so $y=2y^2$. Therefore...

Comment: got it :) y1=0 ; y2=0,5

Comment: therefore e^(−xπ)=0,5  --> x=-ln(0,5)/π

Comment: Thank you a lot for the hint!